# How to set Money Format in PHP

Tags: php

I am making real estate portal.In that user has entered property value like 
    55,00,000 - 45,35,000 - 30,00,000 and so on.
My Question is ,i want to show those values as 
    55 Lac(s) - 45.35 Lac(s) - 30 Lac(s) so on.So please..suggest me, how can i make this possible.

Thanks

Comment: why not simply show the value divided by 100000?

Comment: Fallen . its not a solution..

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel: I know, I've not added it as answer. But if he only needs x.yz.lac(s) then why shouldn't he use it?

Comment: @Fallen.....Thanks buddy,so simple...I don't know why i dont thinked it.....anyway....thanks....a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal cases money_format is ideal way to go, But as you require to use a 'Lac' like format. You need to write your own code on conditions basis.

First remove all commas from user entered amount. like that

```
$number = str_replace(',', '', $number);
```

Then check and make required string.

```
if($number > 10000000)
{
    $num = ((float)$number) / 10000000;
    $num = $num.' Crore(s)'
}
else if($number > 100000)
{
    $num = ((float)$number) / 100000;
    $num = $num.' Lac(s)'
}
else if($number > 1000)
{
    $num = ((float)$number) / 1000;
    $num = $num.' Thousand(s)'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `money_format()` function in php. http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

To use `money_format()` in window, if you have the Intl extension, you can use

http://de.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php— Format a currency value according to the formatter rules.
Example from Manual

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'ru_RU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
```

Output

```
1.234.567,89 €
1.234.567,89 RUR
1 234 567,89€
1 234 567,89р.
```

Also see my answer on how to parse that formatted money string back into a float:

Comment: *sidenote:* as specified in the documentation, this function output is affected by locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.currency.usage.html) for Zend Framework
and for core php [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

```
string money_format ( string $format , float $number )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
function formatInCurrencyStyle($num){
     $pos = strpos((string)$num, ".");
     if ($pos === false) {
        $decimalpart="00";
     }
     if (!($pos === false)) {
        $decimalpart= substr($num, $pos+1, 2); $num = substr($num,0,$pos);
     }

     if(strlen($num)>3 & strlen($num) <= 12){
         $last3digits = substr($num, -3 );
         $numexceptlastdigits = substr($num, 0, -3 );
         $formatted = makeComma($numexceptlastdigits);
         $stringtoreturn = $formatted.",".$last3digits.".".$decimalpart ;
     }elseif(strlen($num)<=3){
        $stringtoreturn = $num.".".$decimalpart ;
     }elseif(strlen($num)>12){
        $stringtoreturn = number_format($num, 2);
     }

     if(substr($stringtoreturn,0,2)=="-,"){
        $stringtoreturn = "-".substr($stringtoreturn,2 );
     }

     return $stringtoreturn;
 }

 function makeComma($input){ 
     if(strlen($input)<=2)
     { return $input; }
     $length=substr($input,0,strlen($input)-2);
     $formatted_input = makeComma($length).",".substr($input,-2);
     return $formatted_input;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

You can also use `money_format` :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

```
Note:

The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

Note:

The LC_MONETARY category of the locale settings, affects the behavior of this function. Use setlocale() to set to the appropriate default locale before using this function.
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a simple way

```
number_format(200000)  // 200,000
```